# How do i combine NgRx selectors and RxJS operators in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am reading about selectors in ngrx website and am having trouble understanding some code.

This is the [link](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#advanced-example-select-the-last-n-state-transitions) to the code at ngrx website.

Let's examine the technique of combining NgRx selectors and RxJS operators in an advanced example.

In this example, we will write a selector function that projects values from two different slices of the application state. The projected state will emit a value when both slices of state have a value. Otherwise, the selector will emit an undefined value.

index.ts file

```
export const selectProjectedValues = createSelector(
  selectFoo,
  selectBar,
  (foo, bar) => {
    if (foo && bar) {
      return { foo, bar };
    }

    return undefined;
  }
);
```

select-last-state-transition.ts

```
// The number of state transitions is given by the user (subscriber)
export const selectLastStateTransitions = (count: number) => {

  return pipe(
    // Thanks to `createSelector` the operator will have memoization "for free"
    select(selectProjectedValues),
    // Combines the last `count` state values in array
    scan((acc, curr) => {
      return [ curr, ...acc ].filter((val, index) => index < count && val !== undefined)
    }, [] as {foo: number; bar: string}[]) // XX: Explicit type hint for the array.
                                          // Equivalent to what is emitted by the selector
  );
}
```

app.component.ts

```
// Subscribe to the store using the custom pipeable operator
store.pipe(selectLastStateTransitions(3)).subscribe(/* .. */);
```

what i dont understand is this code at select-last-state-transition.ts

```
scan((acc, curr) => {
      return [ curr, ...acc ].filter((val, index) => index < count && val !== undefined)
    }, [] as {foo: number; bar: string}[])
```

And what will be the result of this code

```
// Subscribe to the store using the custom pipeable operator
store.pipe(selectLastStateTransitions(3)).subscribe(/* .. */);
```

Comment: In the scan operator, what part confuses you? the spread operator, the cast, the filter lambda? Or the scan operator itself?

Comment: @Gavin what will be passed to the scan is an object containing just  foo and bar right

Comment: Yes, only if it contains both FOO and BAR otherwise it will return undefined to the Scan, which is basically just an accumulator like Array.Reduce(). The pipe as a whole will return the first {count} items in the accumulated (acc) array.

Comment: @Gavin i think what will be passed to scan is an array of objects. Can you take ur time to answer the question??